# each() working for first element only (dynamically created)

Tags: jquery, each

This is how I dynamically create elements with `#bir`.

```
setInterval(function(){
    baseBody.attr("id", "bir");
    baseBody.after("<td id=eki><p id=test'>Test</p></td>");

    $('#bir').each(function() {
        $(this).after("test");
    });
}, 1000);
```

So, the field goes `testtesttesttesttesttest...`

...but only for the first element. `#bir` gets created correctly for all elements.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selects something by `id`:

```
$('#bir')
```

**Since there should only be a single element on the page with that unique `id`** it makes sense the each only loops once. And I think jquery will only return the first one it finds since there is no reason to look further after finding one since an `id` is unique. You should be looping on a class or something if there will be multiple elements you expect to find.

Comment: Specifically html with elements having the same ID is technically breaking the html specification.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. What I did is:

```
...
    $(baseBody).each(function() {
        $(this).after("test");
    });
...
```

It was not working when I referred to `id`, only jQuery object.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Out of pure interest what is baseBody? I don't see in your code where it comes from and what it is.

Comment: It's a variable that I assigned a CSSPath.